# How can I read user input as an array in Bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

How could I read user input as an array in the `bash` shell?

Comment: I'm presuming you want to read from stdin? My answer will also work with execution like `cat war_and_peace.txt | ./array_test.sh`.

Comment: Or simply `./array_test.sh < war_and_peace.txt`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
while read line
do
    my_array=("${my_array[@]}" $line)
done

echo ${my_array[@]}
```

If you just run it, it will keep reading from standard-input until you hit Ctrl+D (EOF). Afterwards, the lines you entered will be in `my_array`. Some may find this code confusing. The body of the loop basically says `my_array = my_array + element`.

Some interesting pieces of documentation:

- The [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) has a great [**chapter on arrays**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)
- The manpage of the **[read](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html)** builtin
- [15 array examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/) from thegeekstuff.com

Comment: `read -r` is quite useful/important sometimes... Stefano's link to the "read builtin manpage" explains its purpose...(to prevent backslash interpretation).

Comment: Not very useful in a script wanting user input

Answer (score 16):

Read it using this:

```
read -a arr
```

And for printing, use:

```
for elem in ${arr[@]}
do 
  echo $elem
done
```

Answer (score 5):

And one that doesn't recreate the array each time (though requires bash 3.1 or newer):

```
array=()
while IFS= read -r -p "Next item (end with an empty line): " line; do
    [[ $line ]] || break  # break if line is empty
    array+=("$line")
done

printf '%s\n' "Items read:"
printf '  «%s»\n' "${array[@]}"
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for more.

And as always, to avoid writing bugs read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide and avoid the tldp-guides like the Advanced bash scripting guide.

Comment: Nice links... Thanks for pointing out the `IFS` issue. Without nulling it, 'read' sripts all leading and trailing whitespace... and of course the `-r` too...

Answer (score 1):

How about this one-liner ;)

```
arr=( $(cat -) )
echo ${arr[@]}
```

Edit:

In `bash`,

```
arr=(val1 val2 ...)
```

is the way of [assigning to an array](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html). Using it in conjunction with command substitution, you can read in arrays from pipeline which is not possible to use `read` to accomplish this in a straight-forward manner:

```
echo -e "a\nb" | read -a arr
echo ${arr[@]}
```

You will find that it output nothing due to the fact that [`read` does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/read-values-into-a-shell-variable-from-a-pipe) when `stdin` is a pipe since a pipeline may be run in a subshell so that the variable may not be usable at all.

Using the way suggested by this answer:

```
arr=(`echo -e "a\nb"`)
echo ${arr[@]}
```

It gives `a b` which is way simpler and more straight-forward than any workaround given by the answers of [Read values into a shell variable from a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746553/read-values-into-a-shell-variable-from-a-pipe) and [in bash read after a pipe is not setting values](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143958/in-bash-read-after-a-pipe-is-not-setting-values).

Comment: did you test it ?

Comment: @cmak.fr yes it works for me

Comment: @Melebius I have appended an explanation of it and the advantage of this one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

read line 
list=(${line})

for i in ${list[@]};do
  echo $i
done
```

OUTPUT

```
./list-input.sh
banna apple pie
banna
apple
pie
```